# How to get Jquery to work in Docpad in the boilplate skeletion with grunt

Tags: jquery, gruntjs, docpad

This is my grunt configuration file. Jquery is not rendered into the all.min.js, there also is no vendor directory in my out directory, I would assume that docpad is supposed to gernerate teh vendor directory inside of the out directory but it doesnt, why might this be?

```
{
  "min": {
    "js": {
      "src": ["out/vendor/jquery.js", "out/vendor/log.js", "out/vendor/modernizr.js", "out/scripts/script.js"],
      "dest": "out/scripts/all.min.js"
    }
  },
  "concat": {
    "css": {
      "src": ["out/vendor/normalize.css","out/styles/style.css","out/styles/animate.css"],
      "dest": "out/styles/all.css"
    }
  },
  "cssmin": {
    "all": {
      "src": ["out/styles/all.css"],
      "dest": "out/styles/all.min.css"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your vendor directory in the `src/` folder?

Comment: @greduan files/vendor

Comment: When you go to `out/vendor/` can you find the files you're expecting there? If you can't that may be the reason you're having trouble and that would be something to investigate. On a different note, you should use a CDN for stuff like jQuery, makes it easier on the user's internet since it's usually in the cache. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar yet seemingly different issue @ [How to have a the docpad grunt skeleton min vendor js files with live reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774542/how-to-have-a-the-docpad-grunt-skeleton-min-vendor-js-files-with-live-reload)

If you wanted CDN caching advantage for jQuery you'd want to call it directly on a template instead of through grunt (then you're dealing with caching 24k vs another httprequest). There are other vendor scripts one might want to be able to use with this skeleton however. :)

not allowed to comment yet, but I felt this might be of some use. not an answer. aside from copying out `/src/` dir out and just reinstalling the skeleton again. :p sometimes docpad gets a little wonky.